# Getting element from a `Vec<Vec<u8>>` very slow

Tags: performance, vector, indexing, rust

I'm running the following snippet of code (the std::time objects are just there for benchmarking) that gets `u8` elements from a vector of vector of `u8` in a given order and creates a new vector with these objects in this order.

```
for idx in cur_prefix_ref.iter() {

     let now = std::time::Instant::now();

     let elapsed_first = now.elapsed();

     unsafe {
         val = *data.get_unchecked(*idx as usize).get_unchecked(j);
     }

     let elapsed_second = now.elapsed();

     new_add.push(val);

    if val == 0 {
        zero_tot += 1;
    } else if val == 1 {
        one_tot += 1;
    }

    if (ct == 0) || (ct_extra == fm_gap) {
        occ_positions[0].push(zero_tot);
        occ_positions[1].push(one_tot);
        ct_extra = 0;
   
    }

    ct += 1;
    ct_extra += 1;

    let elapsed_third = now.elapsed();

    elapse1.push(elapsed_first);
    elapse2.push(elapsed_second);
    elapse3.push(elapsed_third);
}
```

In my full code this inner loop ends up running hundreds of millions of times so I'm trying to optimise it as much as possible. According to be benchmarking, I seem to be spending the vast majority of the loop time in looking up values from my `Vec<Vec<u8>>`, on the line `val = *data.get_unchecked(*idx as usize).get_unchecked(j);`, see below which benchmarks some `elapsed_first,elapsed_second,elapsed_third` times from different iterations of this loop (the i^th element of each list is from the same run):

```
First: [27ns, 23ns, 21ns, 24ns, 27ns, 23ns, 28ns, 23ns, 26ns, 23ns, 21ns, 22ns, 27ns, 27ns, 28ns, 23ns, 25ns, 24ns, 26ns, 25ns, 22ns, 24ns, 24ns, 28ns, 28ns, 28ns, 26ns, 22ns, 22ns, 21ns]

Second: [538ns, 695ns, 550ns, 486ns, 627ns, 615ns, 562ns, 570ns, 661ns, 521ns, 617ns, 358ns, 444ns, 560ns, 540ns, 471ns, 656ns, 336ns, 233ns, 209ns, 433ns, 373ns, 1.427µs, 542ns, 708ns, 288ns, 304ns, 608ns, 297ns, 252ns]

Third: [612ns, 736ns, 587ns, 525ns, 665ns, 658ns, 608ns, 614ns, 701ns, 560ns, 656ns, 395ns, 482ns, 606ns, 578ns, 510ns, 696ns, 374ns, 270ns, 246ns, 470ns, 416ns, 1.47µs, 583ns, 751ns, 327ns, 348ns, 645ns, 334ns, 289ns]
```

I've been trying to understand why this simple vector lookup is the bit that takes by far the most time compared to everything else and still haven't figured it out. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the full function which this code comes from:

```
pub fn spaced_pbwt(vcf: &VCFData, pbwt_cols: &Vec<SiteRow>, fm_gap: u32) -> SpacedPbwt {

    let now = std::time::Instant::now();

    let data_positions: Vec<u32> = vcf.positions.clone();
    let mut pbwt_positions: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mut insert_positions: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let data: &Vec<Vec<u8>> = &vcf.vcf_data;

    let mut col_set: HashSet<u32> = HashSet::new();

    let mut n: usize = 0;

    for col in pbwt_cols {
        let pos = col.position;
        col_set.insert(pos);
        n += 1;
    }

    let m = data.len();
    let n_full = data[0].len();

    let n_other = n_full-n;

    let mut is_pbwt_col :Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(n_full+1);
    let mut pbwt_positions: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mut inserted_positions: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mut prefixes : Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::with_capacity(n+1);
    let mut divergences : Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::with_capacity(n+1);
    let mut binaries: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::with_capacity(n_full+1);


    let cur_prefix : Vec<u32> = Vec::from_iter(0..m as u32);
    let cur_divergence : Vec<u32> = vec![0; m];
    let mut j: usize = 0;
    let mut j_pbwt = 0;

    let mut count_vec: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mut occ_vec : Vec<Vec<Vec<u32>>> = Vec::new();

    prefixes.push(cur_prefix);
    divergences.push(cur_divergence);

    let mut cur_prefix_ref: &Vec<u32> = &(prefixes[prefixes.len()-1]);
    let mut cur_divergence_ref: &Vec<u32> = &divergences[divergences.len()-1];

    let mut ct: i32 = 0;
    let mut ct_extra: u32 = 0;
    let mut zero_tot: u32 = 0;
    let mut one_tot: u32 = 0;
    let mut occ_positions: Vec<Vec<u32>> = vec![Vec::new(),Vec::new()];
    let mut new_add: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(m);

    let mut a: Vec<u32> = Vec::with_capacity(m);
    let mut b: Vec<u32> = Vec::with_capacity(m);
    let mut d: Vec<u32> = Vec::with_capacity(m);
    let mut e: Vec<u32> = Vec::with_capacity(m);

    let mut bin_values: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(m);

    let mut elapse1 = Vec::new();
    let mut elapse2 = Vec::new();
    let mut elapse3 = Vec::new();

    for col in &vcf.positions {
        if !col_set.contains(&col) {


            ct = 0;
            ct_extra = 0;
            zero_tot = 0;
            one_tot = 0;
            occ_positions = vec![Vec::new(),Vec::new()];

            new_add = Vec::with_capacity(m);

            let mut val: u8;
            for idx in cur_prefix_ref.iter() {

                let now = std::time::Instant::now();

                let elapsed_first = now.elapsed();

                unsafe {
                val = *data.get_unchecked(*idx as usize).get_unchecked(j);
                }

                let elapsed_second = now.elapsed();

                new_add.push(val);

                if val == 0 {
                    zero_tot += 1;
                } else if val == 1 {
                    one_tot += 1;
                }

                if (ct == 0) || (ct_extra == fm_gap) {
                    occ_positions[0].push(zero_tot);
                    occ_positions[1].push(one_tot);
                    ct_extra = 0;
    
                }

                ct += 1;
                ct_extra += 1;

                let elapsed_third = now.elapsed();

                elapse1.push(elapsed_first);
                elapse2.push(elapsed_second);
                elapse3.push(elapsed_third);
            }

            binaries.push(new_add);
            is_pbwt_col.push(0);
            inserted_positions.push(*col);
            count_vec.push(zero_tot);
            occ_vec.push(occ_positions);


        } else {


            a = Vec::with_capacity(m);
            b = Vec::with_capacity(m);
            d = Vec::with_capacity(m);
            e = Vec::with_capacity(m);

            bin_values = Vec::with_capacity(m);

            let mut p: u32 = j_pbwt+1;
            let mut q: u32 = j_pbwt+1;

            occ_positions = vec![Vec::new(),Vec::new()];

            ct = 0;
            ct_extra = 0;
            zero_tot = 0;
            one_tot = 0;

            let mut cur_allele: u8;
            for (idx,start_point) in
            cur_prefix_ref.iter().zip(cur_divergence_ref.iter()) {

                let idx_val = *idx;

                unsafe {
                cur_allele = *data.get_unchecked(idx_val as usize).get_unchecked(j);
                }


                bin_values.push(cur_allele);

                let st = *start_point;

                if st > p {
                p = st;
                }

                if st > q {
                q = st;
                }

                if cur_allele == 0 {
                    a.push(idx_val);
                    d.push(p);
                    p = 0;

                    zero_tot += 1;
                }
    
                if cur_allele == 1 {
                    b.push(idx_val);
                    e.push(q);
                    q = 0;
    
                    one_tot += 1;
                }

                if (ct == 0) || (ct_extra == fm_gap) {
                    occ_positions[0].push(zero_tot);
                    occ_positions[1].push(one_tot);
                    ct_extra = 0;
    
                }
                ct += 1;
                ct_extra += 1;
            
            }  

            
            let mut new_prefix = a;
            new_prefix.append(&mut b);
            let mut new_divergence = d;
            new_divergence.append(&mut e);


            prefixes.push(new_prefix);
            divergences.push(new_divergence);
            binaries.push(bin_values);

            cur_prefix_ref = &(prefixes[prefixes.len()-1]);
            cur_divergence_ref = &divergences[divergences.len()-1];

            count_vec.push(zero_tot);
            occ_vec.push(occ_positions);

            is_pbwt_col.push(1);
            pbwt_positions.push(*col);

        }
        j += 1;

    }

    let elapsed = now.elapsed();

    println!("Calc Time: {:.4?}", elapsed);

    println!("First: {:?}", &elapse1[500..530]);
    println!("Second: {:?}", &elapse2[500..530]);
    println!("Third: {:?}", &elapse3[500..530]);


    return SpacedPbwt {
        num_samples: m as u32,
        num_pbwt_sites: n as u32,
        num_inserted_sites: n_other as u32,
        num_total_sites: n_full as u32,

        pbwt_positions: pbwt_positions,
        inserted_positions: inserted_positions,
        all_positions: data_positions,
        pbwt_col_flags: is_pbwt_col,

        bin_pbwt: binaries,
        count: count_vec,
        occ_list: occ_vec,
        fm_gap: fm_gap,
        
    };
}
```

EDIT EDIT:

Here is a modified version of the file that everybody should be able to run on their machine and does exhibit the behaviour I'm concerned about. It only uses the `rand` crate as a dependency:

```
use rand::{seq::IteratorRandom, thread_rng}; // 0.6.1
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform};

use std::collections::HashSet;

pub fn spaced_pbwt(data: &Vec<Vec<u8>>, fm_gap: u32) -> () {

    let now = std::time::Instant::now();


    let m = data.len();
    let n = data[0].len();
    let half_n = n/2;
    
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let sample: Vec<u32> = (0u32..n as u32).collect();
    let perm = sample.iter().choose_multiple(&mut rng, half_n);

    let mut cols_to_permute: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();

    for i in perm {
        cols_to_permute.push(*i);
    }
    

    let mut col_set: HashSet<u32> = HashSet::new();

    let mut n: usize = 0;

    for col in &cols_to_permute {
        col_set.insert(*col);
        n += 1;
    }

    let m = data.len();
    let n_full = data[0].len();

    let n_other = n_full-n;

    let mut is_pbwt_col :Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(n_full+1);
    let mut pbwt_positions: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mut inserted_positions: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mut prefixes : Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::with_capacity(n+1);
    let mut divergences : Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::with_capacity(n+1);
    let mut binaries: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::with_capacity(n_full+1);


    let cur_prefix : Vec<u32> = Vec::from_iter(0..m as u32);
    let cur_divergence : Vec<u32> = vec![0; m];
    let mut j: usize = 0;
    let mut j_pbwt = 0;

    let mut count_vec: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mut occ_vec : Vec<Vec<Vec<u32>>> = Vec::new();

    prefixes.push(cur_prefix);
    divergences.push(cur_divergence);

    let mut cur_prefix_ref: &Vec<u32> = &(prefixes[prefixes.len()-1]);
    let mut cur_divergence_ref: &Vec<u32> = &divergences[divergences.len()-1];

    let mut ct: i32 = 0;
    let mut ct_extra: u32 = 0;
    let mut zero_tot: u32 = 0;
    let mut one_tot: u32 = 0;
    let mut occ_positions: Vec<Vec<u32>> = vec![Vec::new(),Vec::new()];
    let mut new_add: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(m);

    let mut a: Vec<u32> = Vec::with_capacity(m);
    let mut b: Vec<u32> = Vec::with_capacity(m);
    let mut d: Vec<u32> = Vec::with_capacity(m);
    let mut e: Vec<u32> = Vec::with_capacity(m);

    let mut bin_values: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(m);

    let mut elapse1 = Vec::new();
    let mut elapse2 = Vec::new();
    let mut elapse3 = Vec::new();

    for col in 0..n {
        if !col_set.contains(&(col as u32)) {


            ct = 0;
            ct_extra = 0;
            zero_tot = 0;
            one_tot = 0;
            occ_positions = vec![Vec::new(),Vec::new()];

            new_add = Vec::with_capacity(m);

            let mut val: u8;
            for idx in cur_prefix_ref.iter() {

                let now = std::time::Instant::now();

                let elapsed_first = now.elapsed();

                unsafe {
                val = *data.get_unchecked(*idx as usize).get_unchecked(j);
                }

                let elapsed_second = now.elapsed();

                new_add.push(val);

                if val == 0 {
                    zero_tot += 1;
                } else if val == 1 {
                    one_tot += 1;
                }

                if (ct == 0) || (ct_extra == fm_gap) {
                    occ_positions[0].push(zero_tot);
                    occ_positions[1].push(one_tot);
                    ct_extra = 0;
    
                }

                ct += 1;
                ct_extra += 1;

                let elapsed_third = now.elapsed();

                elapse1.push(elapsed_first);
                elapse2.push(elapsed_second);
                elapse3.push(elapsed_third);
            }

            binaries.push(new_add);
            is_pbwt_col.push(0);
            inserted_positions.push(col as u32);
            count_vec.push(zero_tot);
            occ_vec.push(occ_positions);


        } else {


            a = Vec::with_capacity(m);
            b = Vec::with_capacity(m);
            d = Vec::with_capacity(m);
            e = Vec::with_capacity(m);

            bin_values = Vec::with_capacity(m);

            let mut p: u32 = j_pbwt+1;
            let mut q: u32 = j_pbwt+1;

            occ_positions = vec![Vec::new(),Vec::new()];

            ct = 0;
            ct_extra = 0;
            zero_tot = 0;
            one_tot = 0;

            let mut cur_allele: u8;
            for (idx,start_point) in
            cur_prefix_ref.iter().zip(cur_divergence_ref.iter()) {

                let idx_val = *idx;

                unsafe {
                cur_allele = *data.get_unchecked(idx_val as usize).get_unchecked(j);
                }


                bin_values.push(cur_allele);

                let st = *start_point;

                if st > p {
                p = st;
                }

                if st > q {
                q = st;
                }

                if cur_allele == 0 {
                    a.push(idx_val);
                    d.push(p);
                    p = 0;

                    zero_tot += 1;
                }
    
                if cur_allele == 1 {
                    b.push(idx_val);
                    e.push(q);
                    q = 0;
    
                    one_tot += 1;
                }

                if (ct == 0) || (ct_extra == fm_gap) {
                    occ_positions[0].push(zero_tot);
                    occ_positions[1].push(one_tot);
                    ct_extra = 0;
    
                }
                ct += 1;
                ct_extra += 1;
            
            }  

            
            let mut new_prefix = a;
            new_prefix.append(&mut b);
            let mut new_divergence = d;
            new_divergence.append(&mut e);


            prefixes.push(new_prefix);
            divergences.push(new_divergence);
            binaries.push(bin_values);

            cur_prefix_ref = &(prefixes[prefixes.len()-1]);
            cur_divergence_ref = &divergences[divergences.len()-1];

            count_vec.push(zero_tot);
            occ_vec.push(occ_positions);

            is_pbwt_col.push(1);
            pbwt_positions.push(col as u32);

        }
        j += 1;

    }

    let elapsed = now.elapsed();

    println!("Calc Time: {:.4?}", elapsed);

    println!("First: {:?}", &elapse1[500..530]);
    println!("Second: {:?}", &elapse2[500..530]);
    println!("Third: {:?}", &elapse3[500..530]);

}


fn main() {

    let m = 4000;
    let n = 50000;

    let step: Uniform<u8> = Uniform::new(0,2);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut data = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..m {
        let choices: Vec<u8> = step.sample_iter(&mut rng).take(n).collect();
        data.push(choices);
    }
    
    let fm = 2;
    spaced_pbwt(&data,fm);
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this is running a release build?

Comment: How many elements are in the vectors?

Comment: Also, 500ns doesn't seem that bad if this has to hit main memory. Whats your index pattern like? Is it linear or random?

Comment: it looks like you're iterating over `j` and then `idx` which won't best take advantage of cache locality, so depending on the size of your data, you may be fetching from main memory each time (though I don't know if that alone explains the numbers)

Comment: Two obvious suggestions assuming that the datastructure is rectangular and not too ragged would be to use a Vec<u8> as a matrix, with `idx * rowlength + j` as your index, and secondly to see if you can invert whatever loop is producing j to be inside this loop so you have rowwise access.

Comment: @user1937198 Yep, release build.

Comment: @PitaJ The Vec<Vec<u8>> is essentially 4,000*50,000 (so first vec has 4000 members and each of those members has 50,000 elements)

Comment: @user1937198 idx is essentially random.

Comment: @kmdreko yes I am iterating over j in an outer loop. Would it bet better to "transpose" my data object so that I access it like `data[j][idx]` in this loop?

Comment: Why not use a single `Vec`? It takes time to retrieve data from main memory, so your solution doubles the time it takes to access data in most cases. Plus, it makes it very difficult for the CPU cache to help you.

Comment: @HadiKhan Its better if idx is predictable/there is a high chance of idx increasing by less than 64. Because then you can make better use of the cache hierachy. Otherwise, it probably won't help much. Is j more predictable, and is there anything  stopping you from moving it to be the inner loop?

Comment: @HadiKhan they're suggesting you move the `for j in ..` within the `for idx in cur_prefix_ref.iter()` loop, if possible.

Comment: @user1937198 j is completely predictable, it just iterates from 0 to around 50,000 . I can't move j to be the inner loop as the results from j = 0 influence very strongly the results for j = 1 (they change cur_prefix_ref), however I can change my `data` object to index on j first and idx second if that might help.

Comment: @PitaJ I can't move the j loop inside the cur_prefix_ref loop, but I can transpose the construction of the `data` object so that it indexes on j first and idx second. Would that help?

Comment: Indexing on `j` first and `idx` second would help, but probably not by much. You're going to be limited by memory access times since you're skipping around so much.

Comment: @PitaJ right, changing around the indexing would mean in the inner loop I only read from a single data[j] vector (but skipping around it a lot). At 50,000 u8 this is 50KB only. Is there a way to tell Rust to force this object onto the CPU cache?

Comment: The term you're looking for is [prefetch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/arch/x86_64/fn._mm_prefetch.html).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Although, with this access pattern with the current datastructure, _mm_prefetch doesn't seem like it would be that useful. The indexes are more than 4KB apart, so each one would be a seperate page unless huge pages is configured, and mm_prefetch runs into TLB and page fault issues across page boundary's.

Which is another consideration you may want  use perf to profile TLB misses in this code. If you can rearrange the datastructure so j is first, then maybe you will have more than one idx per page?

Comment: OP, can you provide a complete code sample that exhibits this behavior? That way people can measure for themselves, or assess the generated assembly, or whatever else to help you out.

Comment: @kmdreko Added full code although there are still a bunch of structs I'm not including as the full project spread out over 10+ files. Let me know if you'd like me to strip it down and create a version that other people can actually run.

Comment: @kmdreko Just added a version that everybody should be able to run on their machines.

Comment: @HadiKhan would you mind adding tests so that we can confirm it still works, if we refactor it?

Comment: Also note that you won't get orders of magnitude from those kind of optimizations. Are you sure the algorithm itself can't get optimized further? Just checking.

Comment: @Finomnis I have a test in the last version of the code I've posted, if you run it it should (at least it does on my machine) show that the numbers in the list "Third" are slightly bigger than the numbers in the list "Second" which are significantly bigger than the numbers in the list "First", hence showing the code is spending a lot of time in the "look up a value from the Vec<Vec<u8>> bit". I'm pretty sure the algorithm itself can't be optimised further, but there is some C code I'm comparing to which is 3x faster and basically does this step too.

Comment: There is no instruction between the beginning of the time measurement and "First". So I'm not surprised that the first time is really short :D

Comment: I don't see a test?

Comment: @Finomnis Yes, the First list is just there to account for overheads from the .elapsed() function, it's just to show that the extra time between First and Second is caused by the lookup taking a lot of time and not just overheads from the lines used to time the code.

Comment: @Finomnis so if you run the code these lines `println!("First: {:?}", &elapse1[500..530]);`
    `println!("Second: {:?}", &elapse2[500..530]);`
    `println!("Third: {:?}", &elapse3[500..530]);` will print out the differences between the time it takes on your machine and it will follow the pattern of the difference between Second and First being (relatively) huge wile the difference between Third and Second is (relatively) minor, I think that should count as a test, unless you meant something else? If so please let me know and I'll add that too.

Comment: In your example `col` and `j` have always the same value, I think. So if you transpose `data` then you could just do `let data_j = &data[j];` at the beginning of the loop, and then in the hot-line you only need one `get_unchecked()` call.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code (on an `i7-7700HQ`), I got these numbers

```
First: [16ns, 17ns, 16ns, 16ns, 16ns, 17ns, 15ns, 15ns, 16ns, 17ns, 16ns, 16ns, 16ns, 16ns, 16ns, 16ns, 16ns, 15ns, 16ns, 15ns, 16ns, 16ns, 17ns, 16ns, 17ns, 16ns, 15ns, 16ns, 16ns, 16ns]
Second: [107ns, 104ns, 171ns, 109ns, 101ns, 112ns, 116ns, 169ns, 184ns, 177ns, 103ns, 108ns, 105ns, 79ns, 110ns, 112ns, 109ns, 165ns, 157ns, 104ns, 104ns, 409ns, 104ns, 107ns, 111ns, 104ns, 104ns, 104ns, 106ns, 117ns]
Third: [132ns, 126ns, 202ns, 132ns, 133ns, 140ns, 147ns, 197ns, 216ns, 207ns, 136ns, 138ns, 405ns, 105ns, 149ns, 139ns, 142ns, 198ns, 182ns, 126ns, 135ns, 434ns, 128ns, 136ns, 136ns, 127ns, 128ns, 129ns, 136ns, 147ns]
```

Which has vastly different proportions, than your results. Since you said, there is a C program that runs faster, it should not be a problem with your system.

The next thing I can think about is you need a `cargo clean` and recompile the whole thing. Sometimes (I am on the nightly compiler) I had an issue, that made recompiled binaries slow, maybe because of some code-layout issue, compiler stuff idk. A clean build usually fixed it.

Next, you can try using link time optimization. Add this to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[profile.lto]
inherits = "release"
lto = true
```

Then run the profile with

```
cargo run --profile lto
```

Third, use a single array, like some comments said. The `ndarray` crate is perfect for this. For me it brings down the times to

```
First: [18ns, 16ns, 17ns, 16ns, 17ns, 16ns, 18ns, 17ns, 17ns, 17ns, 17ns, 17ns, 17ns, 25ns, 16ns, 17ns, 18ns, 18ns, 17ns, 17ns, 18ns, 17ns, 17ns, 16ns, 17ns, 16ns, 16ns, 17ns, 17ns, 18ns]
Second: [51ns, 49ns, 48ns, 50ns, 51ns, 51ns, 49ns, 48ns, 48ns, 49ns, 50ns, 48ns, 53ns, 66ns, 49ns, 53ns, 52ns, 50ns, 50ns, 49ns, 53ns, 51ns, 47ns, 50ns, 52ns, 50ns, 48ns, 48ns, 48ns, 50ns]
Third: [77ns, 77ns, 75ns, 74ns, 83ns, 81ns, 75ns, 72ns, 81ns, 74ns, 82ns, 79ns, 552ns, 99ns, 81ns, 76ns, 79ns, 74ns, 77ns, 73ns, 86ns, 76ns, 75ns, 80ns, 85ns, 75ns, 74ns, 73ns, 74ns, 76ns]
```

```
use ndarray::Array2;

use std::collections::HashSet;

pub fn spaced_pbwt(data: &Array2<u8>, fm_gap: u32) -> () {

    let now = std::time::Instant::now();


    let (m, n) = data.dim();
    let half_n = n/2;
    ...
    unsafe {
      val = *data.uget((idx as usize, j));
    }
    ...

}

fn main() {

    let m = 4000;
    let n = 50000;

    let step: Uniform<u8> = Uniform::new(0,2);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    let mut data2 = Vec::with_capacity(m*n);

    for _ in 0..m {
        let choices: Vec<u8> = step.sample_iter(&mut rng).take(n).collect();
        data2.extend_from_slice(&choices);
        data.push(choices);
    }
    
    let fm = 2;
    spaced_pbwt(&Array2::from_shape_vec((m, n), data2).unwrap(),fm);
    //spaced_pbwt_vecs(&data,fm);
}
```